# Botões "Gostar" e "Não Gostar" não funcionam sem actualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel-5.3

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de post, onde em cada post visualizado, coloquei um botão "Gosto" e um "Não Gosto". Implementei um código que actualiza a página quando um dos botões é clicado, funcionou perfeitamente, adicionando 1, no total_gosto ou total_nao_gosto. O meu problema é salvar os dados dinamicamente, sem actualizar a página.

Abaixo vai o que já tentei e não resulta:

**DB**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Controller**

```
 // Adicionar gosto sem actualização da página
public function adicionarGosto()
{
    $id = Input::get('post_id');
    $post = Post::find($id);
    if (Cache::has('voto '.$id)==false)
    {
        Cache::add('voto '.$id,'contador',0.30);
        $post->totalgosto_pt+=1;
        $post->save();
        return \Response::json(array('status'=>'sim','qtde'=>$post->totalgosto_pt));
    }
    else
    {
        return \Response::json(array('status'=>'nao'));
    }
}

// Adicionar não gosto sem actualização da página
public function adicionarNaoGosto()
{
    $id = Input::get('post_id');
    $post = Post::find($id);
    if (Cache::has('voto '.$id)==false)
    {
        Cache::add('voto '.$id,'contador',0.30);
        $post->totalnaogosto_pt+=1;
        $post->save();
        return \Response::json(array('status'=>'sim','qtde'=>$post->totalnaogosto_pt));
    }
    else
    {
        return \Response::json(array('status'=>'nao'));
    }
}
```

**View**

```html
{{--Botões like e unlike sem actualização da página--}}
<div classe"row">
                           <a class="btn btn-primary _btnGostei">Gostei <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up">({!! $post->totalgosto_pt !!})</i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger _btnNaoGostei">Não Gostei <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down">({!! $post->totalnaogosto_pt !!})</i></a>


              
                        </div>



                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{!! $post->id_pt !!}">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("._btnGostei").click(function () {
                                $.post("/portal/adicionar-gosto",{post_id:$('input[name="post_id"]').attr("value"),_token:$('input[name="_token"]').attr("value")},function (response) {
                                    if(response.status=="sim")
                                    {
                                        $("._btnGostei").html("Gostei ("+response.qtde+")");
                                    }

                                });

                            });

                            $("._btnNaoGostei").click(function () {
                                $.post("/portal/adicionar-naogosto",{post_id:$('input[name="post_id"]').attr("value"),_token:$('input[name="_token"]').attr("value")},function (response) {
                                    if(response.status=="sim")
                                    {
                                        $("._btnNaoGostei").html("Não Gostei ("+response.qtde+")");
                                    }

                                });

                            });
                        </script>
```

**Rotas**

```
//Gosto e não gosto sem actualização da página
```

Route::post('/portal/adicionar-gosto', 'Painel\PostController@adicionarGosto');
Route::post('/portal/adicionar-naogosto', 'Painel\PostController@adicionarNaoGosto');

**GUI**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que "não resulta"? Tem algum erro? Verificou no console do navegador se o request é feito?

Comment: @tvdias sou principiante na programação web, não sei como verificar no navegador se o request é feito. agradeço que me dê algumas dicas para o efeito.

Comment: Não dá nenhum erro, mas também não salva no banco.

Comment: Qual é o seu navegador? Geralmente é com o F12, há um console com os pedidos (aparecem somente os feitos após o console ser aberto) e também os erros de javascript.

Comment: Use [JQuery.Ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) para enviar uma requisição ao servidor sem ter que atualizar a página.

Comment: @tvdias, estou a usar o torch.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, não daria no mesmo que o que ele já usa, o `$.post`?

Comment: @Augusto Vasques, sou novo na programação web.

Comment: @tvdias, já cliquei F12, não aparece nada.

Comment: Pessoal, há mais de um mês que luto com esse problema!

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo ajudar com o torch, mas vc pode experimentar com outro navegador...

Comment: Não é uma coisa difícil. Nessa outra pergunta é feito exatamente o mesmo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433548/atualizar-div-com-coment%c3%a1rios-a-cada-coment%c3%a1rio-inserido/433571#433571

Comment: @tvdias, tinha um problema na tecla F12 mas já resolvi, consegui encontrar o console e notei que no javascript do _btnGostei, está marcado com a cor amarela. O que significa isso?

Comment: Com o console aberto, busque uma aba em que exiba is requests que são feitos, aperte um dos botões e verifique se o request é bem sucedido.

Comment: @tvdias, fiz e pude verificar um erro, que vou actualizar agora o post, para poderes ver. Será a última imagem do post.

Comment: já actualizei! @tvdias.

Comment: Esse erro é pq "$" não foi encontrado. Geralmente ele é o jQuery. Assim sendo, falta adicioná-lo como referência à sua página.

Comment: @tvdias, adicionei o link do jQuery  antes da tag <script> e resultou! está fazendo o eu queria! muito obrigado @tvdias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro é pq "$" não foi encontrado. Geralmente ele é o jQuery. Assim sendo, falta adicioná-lo como referência à sua página.

Para isso, [faça o download do mesmo na página oficial](https://jquery.com/download/) e adicione este código à sua página: `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`, alterando o src de acordo com a localização do *.js baixado.

Em alternativa ao download, o mesmo também pode ser adicionado a partir de uma CDN, como cloudflare: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`