# Como enviar dados para o PHP em tempo real?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Fala pessoal, tudo bem? Estou tentando fazer um sistema que calcula orçamentos dependendo do produto e suas características.

Estou usando o seguinte código para resgatar os dados dos produtos do banco de dados, em radio buttons (Pro usuário ter a chance de escolher apenas um por vez)

```
<p>Selecionar Produto</p> <input type="search" name="" id="">
            <div class="results" id="results">

            <?php

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo("<input type='radio' id='radio' name='radio' value=".$row['price'].">");
                echo ("<label for='radio'>". $row['nome']. "</label> <br>");
            }
            ?>
```

Eu estava tentando usar a $row['price'] no value com a intenção de usar esse valor no Javascript pra fazer os calculos, da seguinte maneira:

```
function Calc(){
    var price= document.getElementById("radio").getAttribute("value");
    price = price * 2 + 0.2;

    console.log(price);
}
```

Não obtive muito sucesso pois o Javascript não usava o Value apenas do item selecionado e sim do primeiro Radio.
De qualquer forma preciso que o calculo, como o feito acima seja feito no Back-end em PHP e seja retornado, sei que há como fazer com AJAX, mas não faço ideia de como.

Além de tudo, há outra selectbox que deveria mostrar as cores do produto, de acordo com o produto que foi selecionado nos Radio Buttons anteriores. Como mostrar apenas as cores do item selecionado (Já tenho uma tabela com uma coluna contendo as cores).

Comment: Não pode repetir id's. Use class em vez disso. Um id é como CPF, cada pessoa tem o seu. Imagine se mais de uma pessoa tivesse o mesmo CPF? Como vc iria identificá-la? Pegar a primeira pessoa com aquele CPF? É o que está acontecendo no seu código. O JavaScript está pegando o primeiro id que encontrar e ignorando o resto.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Procure ser mais claro na sua pergunta, escrevê-la com cuidado para que os outros entendam qual é o problema. Não misture diversos temas na mesma pergunta. Essas são algumas dicas para conseguir obter respostas e evitar que a sua pergunta seja fechada.

Comment: Poderiam justificar o voto contra em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434851/172323?

Comment: Conseguiu verificar as respostas? Não esqueça de aceitar uma delas.

Answer (score 1):

Há diversos problemas no código apresentado e na própria pergunta. Diversas perguntas são feitas, o que dificulta saber o que exatamente vc espera receber como resposta. O título não me parece nada relacionado com o texto da pergunta. E por ai vai...

Quanto ao HTML

- Não esqueça de fechar as suas tags HTML
- Não repita os IDs dos elementos

Para endereçar `Javascript não usava o Value apenas do item selecionado e sim do primeiro Radio`, é preciso usar `$("input[name='radio']:checked").val()` para pegar o valor do item selecionado dado o nome dos inputs.

Como fazer um request ajax deve ser pesquisado no site, pois há diversas perguntas como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433711/bot%C3%B5es-gostar-e-n%C3%A3o-gostar-n%C3%A3o-funcionam-sem-actualizar-a-p%C3%A1gina/433864) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433548/atualizar-div-com-coment%C3%A1rios-a-cada-coment%C3%A1rio-inserido/433571).

E posteriormente crie uma nova pergunta para esclarecer o que pretende com

> Além de tudo, há outra selectbox que deveria mostrar as cores do produto, de acordo com o produto que foi selecionado nos Radio Buttons anteriores. Como mostrar apenas as cores do item selecionado (Já tenho uma tabela com uma coluna contendo as cores).

Comment: Poderia justificar o voto contra?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Vamos lá, primeiro para usar o ajax você precisar fazer:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "php/calcula-nome-do-arquivo-php-que-vai-executar-sua-tarefa.php",
    data: { token: currentToken }
}) 
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Na linha:

```
data: { token: currentToken }
```

Perceba que eu passei informações para a página PHP
Só pegar com o

```
$_POST['token']
```

Já nesta peguei a saída do arquivo PHP

Você pode tá usando

```
exit("resposta-do-php");
```

No JS

```
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Sua pergunta poderia tirar a parte de "tempo real", na verdade isto pode confundir outras pessoas ao responder. Boa codificação